# How to use LIKE operator against multiple values

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query :

```
select * from users where mailaddress  
  NOT like '%banned_domain1.com%'  
    AND mailaddress NOT like '%banned_domain2.com%'  
      AND mailaddress NOT like '%banned_domain3.com%' ;
```

I want to make it more simple , I executed this query from command line :

`select * from users where mailaddress
 NOT like ('%banned_domain1.com%','%banned_domain2.com%','%banned_domain3.com%') ;`

I got MySQL error :

`ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: There is a flaw in your logic. Do not match domains using `%`. For example `user@banned_domain1.com.tld` and `user@iamnot_banned_domain1.com` match `%banned_domain1.com%`.

Comment: He probably wanted use wildcards only before domain because these are email adresses so banned domain may be `10minutemail.com` and he wants to SELECT all users using this domain in their e-mail addresses.

Comment: But `%10minutemail.com` matches `110minutemail.com`!

Comment: Then it should be `%@10minutemail.com`. But OP wanted to be in his format, so be it.

Comment: @SalmanA @Mr. Smith yes there is a flaw in matching domains if `REGEXP` doesn't used properly so it is better removing `%` and use the domain name as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`NOT REGEXP`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-not-regexp-function.php)

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE mailaddress NOT REGEXP 'banned_domain1.com|banned_domain2.com|banned_domain3.com';
```

### See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2461f/4)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "Like" use "In" and format the email address like this:

```
select * from users where SUBSTR(mailaddress, INSTR(mailaddress, '@') + 1)
NOT IN ('banned_domain1.com','banned_domain2.com','banned_domain3.com');
```

The SUBSTR will remove the @ and anything preceding it, leaving only the domain name then you can do a perfect comparison without wildcards using IN.

Cheers!

Comment: `IN` cannot utilize the `%` wildcard.

Comment: You're right, I corrected it in a way that it works. :)

Comment: Your answer is better and avoids the flaw in OPs logic.

Comment: Yep, with the REGEXP solution it will also evaluate the part before the domain name and can cause false positives if the banned domain name is a fake like john.com it would cause it to evaluate anyone with an email like peter.john.com@gmail.com as a banned domain.

Answer (score 0):

you have to mention the column every time

```
select * from tasks where title NOT LIKE '%eating lunch%' AND title NOT LIKE '%eating breakfast%' AND title NOT LIKE '%a new task%'
```

however as Bruno Domingues said use NOT IN that will be more easy

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simplify your query. You need one LIKE per condition.

Comment: @Salman A: Yes, that was supposed to be an answer :-) SQL doesn't support a single function for more than one LIKE expression. I didn't know that MySQL features regular expression functions that can solve this. I stand corrected.